# Beautiful_Soup loop over errors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently trying to web scrape numbeo.com with Beautifulsoup to extract the cost of living in ~200 cities in my data frame.

I have the following code but there's an issue in that they report differently in the url. For example, some include only the name of the city while other's end with a hyphen & state abbreviation.

https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Saint-Petersburg-FL
https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Detroit

There are some other issues but how do I reconfigure the code below to jump to another option if there's an error:

```
cofl_list = []
def cost_living(cit):
    cit = str(cit)
    cit = cit.replace('St. Petersburg','Saint-Petersburg-FL')

    cit = cit.replace(' ','-')
    cit = cit.replace('St.','Saint')
    
    url = r.get(f'https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/{cit}')
    soup = bs(url.content)
    cof = soup.find_all('span', attrs= {'class': 'emp_number'} )
    cof_rev = cof[1]
    cof_rev = str(cof_rev)
    cof_rev = cof_rev.replace('$','')
    cof_rev = cof_rev.replace('<span class="emp_number">','')
    cof_rev = cof_rev.replace('</span>','')
    cof_rev = float(cof_rev)

    cofl_list.append(cof_rev)
```

Comment: You can try using `try: except:` statements

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
def my_func():
    try:
        # execute a block of script

    except:
        # if an error occurs in the block under try it gets catched here so You can execute something here
        continue
```

however if there is code in the block after the part that causes the error it will not be executed

Comment: Thanks. Can you lump another try / except under the except?

Comment: @sobcza11 as far as I know that shouldn't be a problem, You can also except multiple errors and handle them differently, like so `except IndexError` and then with the same indentation do another for example `except ValueError` not necessary but just to show You.